# Debian 10: sendmail service stops constantly

Tags: debian, wordpress, sendmail, service, systemctl

Whenever I start `sendmail` service, it reports

```
May 01 00:51:43 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent...
May 01 00:51:43 su[6784]: (to smmsp) root on none
May 01 00:51:43 su[6784]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user smmsp by (uid=0)
May 01 00:51:43 su[6784]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user smmsp
May 01 00:51:43 sm-mta[6807]: starting daemon (8.15.2): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
May 01 00:51:45 sendmail[6733]: Starting Mail Transport Agent (MTA): sendmail.
May 01 00:51:45 systemd[1]: Started LSB: powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent.
```

but after ca. 15-20 seconds I get

```
May 01 00:52:01 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent...
```

I've never encountered this timeout before, and due to it I can't send e-mails using `wp_mail()` function. Using sendmail in CLI sends E-Mail as intended - but the issue is mostly about `wp_mail()`.

Is there any workaround or way to make `sendmail` "persistent"?

[Screenshot of `systemctl status sendmail` output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQbvb.png)